# lfs gcc cannot compile

Tags: ubuntu, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to make the gcc according Linux From Scratch. But I meet an error.
  [**error screen capture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y219J.png)

Additonal information that might be of use:
0. lfs manual version 7.7-systemd
1. I am running ubuntu linux
`uname -r : 4.4.0-142-generic`

2. I  have checked the version and library

```
 bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release
 /bin/sh -> /bin/dash
 Binutils: (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
 bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.2
 /usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/bison.yacc
 bzip2,  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
 Coreutils:  8.21
 diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3
 find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
 GNU Awk 4.0.1
 /usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
 gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
 g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
 (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.14) 2.19
 grep (GNU grep) 2.16
 gzip 1.6
 Linux version 4.4.0-142-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-006) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) ) #168~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan 19 11:26:28 UTC 2019
 m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.17
 GNU Make 3.81
 GNU patch 2.7.1
 Perl version='5.18.2';
 sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
 tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
 makeinfo (GNU texinfo) 5.2
 xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.0alpha
 g++ compilation OK
```

```
 ibgmp.la: not found
 libmpfr.la: not found
 libmpc.la: not found
```

This is the code I am running

```
../gcc-4.9.2/configure                             \
    --target=$LFS_TGT                              \
    --prefix=/tools                                \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS                            \
    --with-newlib                                  \
    --without-headers                              \
    --with-local-prefix=/tools                     \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include \
    --disable-nls                                  \
    --disable-shared                               \
    --disable-multilib                             \
    --disable-decimal-float                        \
    --disable-threads                              \
    --disable-libatomic                            \
    --disable-libgomp                              \
    --disable-libitm                               \
    --disable-libquadmath                          \
    --disable-libsanitizer                         \
    --disable-libssp                               \
    --disable-libvtv                               \
    --disable-libcilkrts                           \
    --disable-libstdc++-v3                         \
    --enable-languages=c,c++
```

**UPDATE**
It is first toolchain build in chapter 5, and i unpacked the gcc sources and working this fresh ones.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to help you, we need some more information. Is there a reason your build lfs 7.7? It's a bit old, latest stable version is 9.0. Also - where in the lfs book is this happening? Is it first toolchain build, second, or maybe final build in chapter 6? Did you deleted gcc directory after previous build, unpacked gcc sources and are working on this fresh ones? Please update your question.

Comment: Oh this is the first time i ask the question and i fell so exceited.Thank you my friends. I update my problem. It seems i shoud use new version 9.0 to learn?

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly advise to use current version of *LFS Book* (9.0 as of time of writing). Version 7.7 you use is almost 5 years old now.

Second, your *host system* (Ubuntu) does not meet LFS requirements:

1. `/bin/sh` should be a link to `/bin/bash`. In your case, it's linked to `/bin/dash`. Simple fix would be to manually change it. As root:

```sh
rm /bin/sh
ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

2. Your *host system* uses EGLIBC instead of GLIBC. EGLIBC was designed for embedded devices, **attempting** to be compatible with standard glibc, and it's discontinued since beginning of 2014 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_GLIBC. Unfortunatelly I have no idea if it's possible to change EGLIBC to GLIBC on Ubuntu (installing glibc and then removing eglibc could work).

Comment: Thanks! Now i use the latest version and i actually meet the symbolic problem. I will take attention to the GLIBC during the study.

Comment: @xiaoWu Great! If my answer did help you, please *accept* it (to mark question as solved) and consider *upvote*. Thanks :)